# Notepad++ forgets the backup settings

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ allows creating un-named files. It periodically saves those and auto-opens those when you close and relaunch notepad++. A great feature when you don't want to spend time naming temporary/scratch-work files and still want to be able to close notepad++  or log off your box etc without losing your work.

The following two check boxes enable this behavior[image]

Recently I noticed, the Enable session snapshot... intermittently (every 4-5 days) looses its setting - it automatically unchecks. When I try to close the Notepad++, it makes me save/back up all un-named files. I have Notepad++ v7.2.2 32-bit version running on Windows 10 64-bit.

Is this a bug in Notepad++? If not a bug, what could be changing this setting?
I deleted all the files in `Backup path` folder to start clean, but no success.

Comment: Have you looked into `session.xml` file, that Notepad++ uses to keep track of opened files between sessions?

Comment: I've noticed this behaviour in the last couple of months.  Luckily all my files are usually still in the backup folder mentioned, but it annoying to have to go and find it each time it does happen

Comment: This is still happening for me on v7.5.6 (64-bit) on Windows 10 64-bit. Quite frustrating.

Comment: This is also happening to me.

Comment: The quality of software, in general, is going down everywhere. People are scrambling for frequent releases at the expense of quality. It's madness and I don't know how long this is going to last.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in Notepad++. The only reason that I update notepad++ is because it constantly bugs me with a popup notification even if I disable updates. Perhaps its time I switched to a different editor.